# Compare timestamps based on multiple criteria from multiple rows and columns

Tags: r, timestamp, match

I have two data frames with timestamps (in as.POSIXct, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") as below.

```
df_ID1
 ID         DATETIME               TIMEDIFF                 EV
  A         2019-03-26 06:13:00    2019-03-26 00:13:00      1
  B         2019-04-03 08:00:00    2019-04-03 02:00:00      1
  B         2019-04-04 12:35:00    2019-04-04 06:35:00      1

df_ID0
  ID         DATETIME                   
  A         2019-03-26 00:02:00         
  A         2019-03-26 04:55:00     
  A         2019-03-26 11:22:00
  B         2019-04-02 20:43:00
  B         2019-04-04 11:03:00
  B         2019-04-06 03:12:00
```

I want to compare the DATETIME in df_ID1 with the DATETIME in df_ID0 that is with the same ID and the DATETIME is "smaller than but closest to" the one in df_ID1,

For the pair in two data frames that matches, I want to further compare the TIMEDIFF in df_ID1 to the matched DATETIME in df_ID0, if TIMEDIFF in df_ID1 greater than the DATETIME in df_ID0, change EV 1 to 4 in df_ID1.

My desired result is

```
 df_ID1
 ID         DATETIME               TIMEDIFF                 EV
  A         2019-03-26 06:13:00    2019-03-26 00:13:00      1
  B         2019-04-03 08:00:00    2019-04-03 02:00:00      4
  B         2019-04-04 12:35:00    2019-04-04 06:35:00      1
```

I've checked how to compare timestamps and calculate the time difference, also how to change values based on criteria...
But I cannot find anything to select the "smaller than but closest to" timestamps and cannot figure out how to apply all these logic too..

Any help would be appreciate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option using nested `mapply`, is to first `split` `df_ID1` and `df_ID0` based on `ID`. Calculate the difference in time between each value in `df_ID1` with that of `df_ID0` of same `ID`. Get the index of "smaller than but closest to" and store it in `inds` and change the value to 4 if the value of corresponding `TIMEDIFF` column is greater than the matched `DATETIME` value.

```
df_ID1$EV[unlist(mapply(function(x, y) {
                   mapply(function(p, q) {
                     vals = as.numeric(difftime(p, y$DATETIME))
                     inds = which(vals == min(vals[vals > 0]))
                     q > y$DATETIME[inds]
                    }, x$DATETIME, x$TIMEDIFF)
                 }, split(df_ID1, df_ID1$ID), split(df_ID0, df_ID0$ID)))] <- 4


df_ID1
#  ID            DATETIME            TIMEDIFF EV
#1  A 2019-03-26 06:13:00 2019-03-26 00:13:00  1
#2  B 2019-04-03 08:00:00 2019-04-03 02:00:00  4
#3  B 2019-04-04 12:35:00 2019-04-04 06:35:00  1
```

**data**

```
df_ID0 <- structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
.Label = c("A", 
"B"), class = "factor"), DATETIME = structure(c(1553529720, 1553547300, 
1553570520, 1554208980, 1554346980, 1554491520), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")

df_ID1 <- structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A", 
"B"), class = "factor"), DATETIME = structure(c(1553551980, 1554249600, 
1554352500), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), TIMEDIFF = 
structure(c(1553530380, 
1554228000, 1554330900), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
EV = c(1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I can run in the example dataset, but in my actual big dataset, I got error: Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "EV", value = c(4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4,  : 
  replacement has 18 rows, data has 11... I'm wondering is it because of the min() doesn't work properly in my dataset otherwise I should get 1:1 match?

Comment: @user10301352 not completely sure, but do you have `NA`s in your dataset. Try using `na.rm = TRUE` parameter in `min`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a for loop keeping in mind that if your actual data base is very big then the overhead would be quite bad performance wise.

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df_1)){
  sub <- subset(df_0, ID == df_1$ID[i]) # filter on ID
  df_0_dt <- max(sub[sub$DATETIME < df_1$DATETIME[i],]$DATETIME) # Take max of those with DATETIME less than (ie less than but closest to)
  if(df_0_dt < df_1$TIMEDIFF[i]){ # final condition
    df_1[i, "EV"] <- 4
  } 
}
```

```
df_1
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  ID    DATETIME            TIMEDIFF               EV
  <chr> <dttm>              <dttm>              <dbl>
1 A     2019-03-26 06:13:00 2019-03-26 00:13:00     1
2 B     2019-04-03 08:00:00 2019-04-03 02:00:00     4
3 B     2019-04-04 12:35:00 2019-04-04 06:35:00     1
```